# Classifying a problem involving matching bit arrays

Tags: algorithms, classification

**First explaining the "reverse" use as a background**:

1. There is an array A which contains N boolean values
2. There is an array B which contains N boolean values
3. I start iterating over array A and for every iteration I increment its current position by 1.
4. When corresponding bits at currentLocationA and currentLocationB in both arrays are `true` then the output become `true`.
5. Only when the current value in arrayA is `true` do I increment current position of arrayB.

The code for the "easy" direction is as following:

```
    var output = [];
    var outputLength = 10;
    var array1 = [false, false, true, true];
    var array2 = [false, true, true];

    var idx1 = -1,
        idx2 = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < outputLength; i++) {
        idx1 = (idx1 + 1) % array1.length;
        output.push(array1[idx1] && array2[idx2]);
        if (array1[idx1] == true) { idx2 = (idx2 + 1) % array2.length };
    }

    return output;
```

Will output:
Result: `false`, `false`, `false`, `true`, `false`, `false`, `true`, `false`, `false`, `false`

This is the simple direction.

**The problem I am looking to classify (and resolve):**

How do I classify the opposite use case:
Given the output/result array - how can I get the input values required in array `A` and `B`? Input will be filled result array and a given size SizeA and SizeB for arrayA and arrayB.

**Note:** If the output array is longer than the input then the inputs wrap around

Comment: Are you interested in deciding *whether* a solution exists, or in finding a solution under the *promise* that it exists?

Comment: First objective is just to classify the problem domain. For implementation obviously whether a solution exists will be dependent on A and B being sufficiently big

Comment: Did t answer you question... for implementation first step is to find whether a solution exists at all meaning whether given sizes of A and B are valid

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify this in your question. You have to explain clearly what problem you’re interested in solving. We can’t second guess you.

Comment: I thought title + “How do I classify the opposite use case” would emphasise that problem classification is the topic?

Comment: One more thing: is SizeA an upper bound on the size of arrayA, or is it exact?

Comment: Exact. You are helping me to formulate the descriptions... sorry about that

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "How do I classify...?"